# Filter, Closure, Functional syntax version of for loop with multiple conditions

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn some ideas of functional programming, as they exist in Swift.

In a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40664463/2109038), it was shown how much better this can be, by [Rickster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957768/rickster) (the guru).

from this:

```
var voiceToUse: AVSpeechSynthesisVoice?
let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()         
for voice in voices {
            if voice.name == "Arthur"
            {
                voiceToUse = voice
            }
        }
```

to this:

```
let voiceToUse = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().filter({ $0.name == "Arthur" }).first
```

Now I'm wondering how this technique can be applied to a problem where there's multiple criteria. Can this functional style be done to this:

```
var voiceToUse: AVSpeechSynthesisVoice?
let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()     
for voice in voices {
                    if voice.name == "Samantha (Enhanced)"  && voice.quality == .enhanced
                    {
                        voiceToUse = voice
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Would `let voiceToUse = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().filter({ $0.name == "Samantha (Enhanced)" && $0.quality == .enhanced }).first` work?

Comment: In Swift 3 you can also combine `filter` and `first` to `first(where: {...})`.

Comment: +1 @MartinR! I'd forgot about that in my other answer. That one's nice because it cuts off evaluating the rest of the sequence after finding a match.

Comment: @MartinR I apologise profusely, my knowledge of syntax is less than my knowledge of semantics, which both sit below my minimal understanding. How do I use what you're suggesting, exactly?

Comment: `let voiceToUse = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().first(where: { .... })` where `....` is the condition to be checked on each array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you want the first element of the array that satisfies the criteria
>   use this.

```
if let voiceToUse = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().first(where: {
        $0.name == "Samantha (Enhanced)" && $0.quality == .enhanced
    }){

      //use the voiceTouse Variable

    }
```

> If you want the last of the element of the array that satisfies the
>   criteria use this.

```
if let voiceToUse = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().reversed().first(where: {
       $0.name == "Samantha (Enhanced)" && $0.quality == .enhanced
    }){

      //use the voiceTouse Variable

    }
```

> yes sure, we can use guard let ...

A guard statement is used to transfer program control out of a scope if one or more conditions aren’t met.
in this example, if the condition is not met, ie there is no element in AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices() that meet the criteria, guard let will transfer the program control out of the check function ,else  if there is the some element in AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices() that meet the criteria, program control goes to the next line after the guard let statement

```
func check(){
guard let voiceToUse =  AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().first(where: {
   $0.name == "Samantha (Enhanced)" && $0.quality == .enhanced
})else{
    return
}
 //use the voiceToUseVariable

}

check()
```

Comment: there may not be any element that satisfies the given criteria in the AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices() , so its better to use optional binding(if let).

Comment: sure we can use guard let ... I have edited my answer.. and added the code for guard let too

Answer (score 4):

Your single condition expression uses two shortcuts in the closure syntax:

1 - If there is a single expression, it's value is returned implicitly

2 - `$0` refers to the first argument - the compiler infers it's type

So, you can expand the expression to multiple clauses as long as it's still a single expression:

```
let voiceToUse = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().filter({ $0.name == "Samantha (Enhanced)"  && $0.quality == .enhanced }).first
```

The equivalent without the two shortcuts is this:

```
let voiceToUseB = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().filter(
{ voice in
    let found:Bool = voice.name == "Samantha (Enhanced)" && voice.quality == .enhanced
    return found
}).first
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that this returns a value of `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice?`, so make sure you account for that.

```
let voiceToUse = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().first(where: { $0.name == "Samantha (Enhanced)" && $0.quality == .enhanced })
```